# How to make alexa sample app (voice service) to call/invoke custom skills?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I have created a Amazon custom skill and using this skill in the test tab, I 'm able to get the intended response in the python code and turn the led on and off.

But I'm not able to make the Sample app (avs-device-sdk alexa voice application) to invoice/call the custom skill. Can you please guide what must be done to make this happen?

This is my first attempt in building custom skill/alexa voice service  and trying my hands out. I 'm unclear what is the next step to make the alexa voice service to talk to the custom skill.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm struggling with a similar problem to call my Alexa Skill using a button on my Homepage.

Comment: Make sure you have the set language to en-US. This is what I have done and it started working.

Comment: Oh. ok. That's not my issue. Thanks for answer.